# "rstanarm does not permit formulas with duplicate group-specific terms", how do I fix this?

Tags: r, regression, bayesian, rstanarm

While trying bayesian approach on regression models using "rstanarm", duplicate group specific terms are not allowed. Is there any solution for this?

`Formula = "SleepTime ~ 1 + WorkingHours + (1 + WorkingHours | JobClass) + Tenure + (1 + Tenure | JobClass)"`

`bayesian = stan_lmer(Formula, data = data_model)`

`Error in check_reTrms(group) : 
  rstanarm does not permit formulas with duplicate group-specific terms.
In this case JobClass is used as a grouping factor multiple times and
(Intercept) is included multiple times.
Consider using || or -1 in your formulas to prevent this from happening.`

Answer (score 2):

By

> Consider using || or -1 in your formulas to prevent this from happening.

it means that

```
SleepTime ~ 1 + WorkingHours + Tenure + (1 + WorkingHours | JobClass) + (-1 + Tenure | JobClass)
```

or

```
SleepTime ~ 1 + WorkingHours + Tenure + (1 + WorkingHours + Tenure || JobClass)
```

would be valid formulas that do not have two (unidentified) intercept-deviation parameters for each level of `JobClass`.

Comment: What is the difference between both the formulas you mentioned?

Comment: The latter assumes that the covariance matrix among the deviations in the parameters by level of `JobClass` is diagonal.

Comment: How can I find the coefficients and predicted SleepTime in the rstanarm similar to lme4 package?

Comment: The `fixef`, `ranef`, and `coef` functions work the same way as in lme4 but are evaluated at the posterior medians. You need to do `as.matrix`, `as.data.frame`, etc. to get the raw draws in order to communicate the uncertainty. In addition, there is `posterior_predict`, which works like `predict` does in the lme4 context, except that it produces draws from the posterior predictive distribution rather than (draws from the posterior distribution of) the conditional expectation.

Comment: What does bayesian[["fitted.values"]] return? Is it the median of the posterior_predict distribution for each data point?
(Here, bayesian is a stanreg object)

Comment: No, it is the linear predictor implied by the median coefficients. It isn't very useful.

Comment: @BenGoodrich I know this thread is old, but I was using it to help with the same problem I encountered. You mention that the the equation with `||` assumes the covariance matrix is diagonal, which I understand, but for the first equation which uses the `(-1+ Tenure | JobClass)` what does the `-1` here say about assumptions of the covariance matrix? Or specifically what is the difference in assumptions between `(-1 + Tenure | JobClass)` and `(1 + Tenure | JobClass)` ? Thanks!!!!