# Formula difference specifying random effects on slope rstanarm

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models, random-effects, rstanarm

I believe the same syntax is used with the `lme4` package as `rstanarm`, but I'm having trouble figuring out exactly what the differences are between the different options when fitting a grouped random effect on the slope.

Say we have a model with formula

```
response ~ fixed + (1 + rand1 | group)
```

What exactly is the differences in assumptions between that and these three other options:

1:

```
response ~ fixed + (0 + rand1 | group)
```

2:

```
response ~ fixed + (-1 + rand1 | group)
```

3:

```
response ~ fixed + (1 + rand1 || group)
```

I know that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61803837/rstanarm-does-not-permit-formulas-with-duplicate-group-specific-terms-how-do) one answer mentioned that the `||` formula assumes the covariance matrix among the deviations in the parameters by level of `group` is diagonal, but it's not clear to me how assumptions about the covariance matrix change between that and say the 1st and 2nd options.

Comment: Is `rand1` continuous or categorical (factor)?

Comment: If `rand1` is continuous, like you suggest by calling it a slope, then options 1 and 2 suppress the intercept and there is only one random parameter (the slope for `rand1`), and no covariance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Options 1 and 2 should give *identical* results: from `?formula`

> The ‘-’ operator removes the specified terms ... It can also used to remove the intercept term: when fitting a linear model ‘y ~ x - 1’ specifies a line through the origin. A model with no intercept can be also specified as ‘y ~ x + 0’ or ‘y ~ 0 + x’

(it is true, but not obvious, that this specification applies here).

### if `rand1` is categorical (i.e., a factor)

Because `(rand1|group)` and (e.g.) `(0+rand1|group)` both specify a general positive-definite covariance matrix ("unstructured"), you should get the same *overall* model fit in both cases (barring effects of the prior).  The difference is in the meaning of the individual elements of the covariance matrix. With `(rand1|group)`, lme4 sets up the standard *treatment contrasts*, so that the first row/column of the covariance matrix corresponds to the variance of the intercept (value of the baseline level) across groups; subsequent rows/columns correspond to variances in *differences between the baseline level and levels 2, 3, ... n*.  With `(0+rand1|group)`, the rows/columns are variances of the measured value in the corresponding group.

### if `rand1` is continuous

This case works differently; here `rand1 | group` gives a random effect of length 2 ({intercept, slope}) with a 2x2 covariance matrix; suppressing the intercept with `+0` or `-1` will produce a scalar-random-effect model that assumes the intercept is constant across groups but the slope varies (i.e., a single parameter estimate describing the among-group variance in the slope).

Comment: Got it. This is helpful. In my particular case, the rand1 is categorical, so this is perfect. Thanks!